# Drupal-8 / Civi 5.32 -- In D8 I see some civi blocks for me to use. Where are they defined?

Tags: civievent, drupal

I've been spending a lot of time in the Civi galaxy learning the ropes.  Now I am moving back to the drupal galaxy.  I know they reside in the same universe and there are some blocks pre-built to expose Civi to Drupal.

Users are one area with overlap.

But Views...  I see some pre-built civi views for me to place in Drupal.  Where are they defined??

There is a pre-built view for upcoming events and I would like to tweak that to only show upcoming events where event type ==x.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a "view" in the drupal meaning of the word. It's coming from here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/6960dd4c1e5e99f8e0b3564dcc15269184d7702d/CRM/Core/Block.php#L523

I think the "right" way to customize this would be with your own drupal module that creates a block that does the same thing but calls that `CRM_Event_BAO_Event::getCompleteInfo(date("Ymd"));` function with the 2nd parameter which allows you to specify type.

I don't know if there's a hook that would allow you to more easily customize it in a supported way. If you want to hack it, just add a second parameter on that line to specify the type.

UPDATE: You could also do this as a drupal "view" if you install civicrm_entity. Views can be displayed as blocks.

Comment: You think thatif I edit my version of that blob and refresh my D8 cache then the my new pseudo block will show up as a block to add to a layout (like the current ones)?

  /**
   * The following blocks are supported.
   *
   * @var int
   */
  const
    CREATE_NEW = 1,
    RECENTLY_VIEWED = 2,
    DASHBOARD = 3,
    ADD = 4,
    LANGSWITCH = 5,
    EVENT = 6,
    FULLTEXT_SEARCH = 7;

Comment: Sort of. You'd need to either hack civi or make your own module. But I've updated answer since you could also do this with civicrm_entity.

Comment: I'll have to address this with the civi entity team but there is an install bug. composer 
    - drupal/civicrm_entity 3.0.0-beta1 requires drupal/civicrm * -> no matching package found.

Comment: Did you see the note at https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/civicrm_entity/tree/8.x-3.x#installing-8x-30-beta2-or-later

Comment: Drupal Module civicrm_entity worked well.  Thank you @Demerit.  I had to git clone the repo since composer require didn't work but otherwise it works fine.